# NextJS 13 entering in a compiling loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

After upgrading my NextJS app to 13.4.4 version I started to encounter many performances problem during execution in my local environment (pages takes more than 10 secs to load).

In detail, my webapp enter in a compiling loop, as image below suggests:

[image]

Working with the app in my local environment has become frustrating.

Does anyone else has the same problem?